# Horizontlal scrolling content

Tags: plugins, sub-menu

i’m looking for a plugin (or something else) that could reproduce the horizontal sub-menu and scrolling content we can see on this page when you click on `oeuvres/expostions/etc…` :

http://www.fillesducalvaire.com/artiste/helena-almeida/

Is there a way to acchive something similar? First i thought using tabs, but the contents of tabs in most wordpress plugin is very limited. I need whole sections of pages to be in each sub-menu like in the exemple above.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jQuery plugin to do this. I think the site you linked uses [FlexSlider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/), you can find some documentation [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/FlexSlider). It shouldn't be too hard to set up.